# MySQL performance comparison between joining table and derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this two queries following and noticed they have a huge performance difference

Query1

```
SELECT count(distinct b.id) FROM tableA as a
    LEFT JOIN tableB as b on a.id = b.aId 
    GROUP BY a.id
```

Query2

```
SELECT count(distinct b.id) FROM tableA as a
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tableB) as b on a.id = b.aId 
    GROUP BY a.id
```

the queries are basically joining one table to another and I noticed that Query1 takes about `80ms` whereas Query2 takes about `2sec` with thousands of data in my system. Could anyone explain me why this happens ? and if it's a wise choice to use only Query2 style whenever I am forced to use it ? or is there a better way to do the same thing but better than Query2 ?

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. One belongs to Oracle, the other to Microsoft. They're hardly the same company..Please use tags that actually apply to your post, and don't just randomly add others because they seem similar. Tags have relevance and meaning here. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for letting me know. I edited it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you replace `tableB` with `(SELECT * FROM tableB)` you are forcing the query engine to materialize a subquery, or intermediate table result.  In other words, in the second query, you aren't actually joining directly to `tableB`, you are joining to some intermediate table.  As a result of this, any indices which might have existed on `tableB` to make the query faster would not be available.  Based on your current example, I see no reason to use the second version.

Under certain conditions you might be forced to use the second version though.  For example, if you needed to transform `tableB` in some way, you might need a subquery to do that.

Comment: The most important point is that materializing the subquery (or derived table as MySQL calls it) prevents the use of indexes.